# Trying to get function to run (and stay running) when triggered by an RTC module

Tags: arduino

So I've written some code which I want to start blinking an LED when the time reaches a certain point each day. The LED should continue to blink until a button is pressed, however for some reason the LED will stop blinking by itself, usually after about 1 minute.

I'm not sure if pin 11 is being activated randomly or if it's just not turning the light on after the timer condition has passed. Do you guys know where I'm going wrong?

```cpp
#include <DS3231.h>

// Init the DS3231 using the hardware interface
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
bool active = false;

void setup()
{
  // Setup Serial connection
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Uncomment the next line if you are using an Arduino Leonardo
  //while (!Serial) {}

  // Initialize the rtc object
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, INPUT);
  // The following lines can be uncommented to set the date and time
//  rtc.setDOW(MONDAY);     // Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
//  rtc.setTime(15, 51, 0);     // Set the time to 12:00:00 (24hr format)
//  rtc.setDate(9, 11, 2017);   // Set the date to January 1st, 2014
}

void loop()
{
  int hour = rtc.getTime().hour;
  int min = rtc.getTime().min;

    // Send time
  Serial.print(hour);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(min);
  Serial.println(" ");

  if(hour == 10 && min == 38) {
    active = true;
  }

  blinker();
}

void blinker() {
  while(active == true) {
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1000);  
    buttonCheck();
  }
}

void buttonCheck() {
  if(digitalRead(11) == 1) {
    Serial.println("Button pushed");
    active = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: My first question is, What is the circuit you are using for your button? Does it uses a PULL UP or PULL DOWN resistor or not?

Comment: Also worth considering would be to use an interrupt for the timer and put the Arduino to sleep the rest of the time.

Comment: @sma I'm pretty new to electronics and I didn't realise there would be a benefit to using a resistor with a micro-controller so no resistor in the circuit. It's just an arduino nano, a DS3231 RTC controller a white LED and a push button.

Comment: @Danny_ds not sure what that means, so I'll give it a google, thanks :

Comment: @Danny_ds ah! That could work but that means I'll have to find another means to make the light blink. Maybe I can do it with a capacitor.

Comment: @Sma switching pin 11 to INPUT_PULLUP and altering the code to check for that worked like a charm. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer thanks to @sma + a bit of code tweaking, basically I turned pin 11 from INPUT to INPUT_PULLUP and reworked the code to intercept that

```
#include <DS3231.h>

// Init the DS3231 using the hardware interface
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
bool active = false;

void setup()
{
  // Setup Serial connection
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Uncomment the next line if you are using an Arduino Leonardo
  //while (!Serial) {}

  // Initialize the rtc object
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // The following lines can be uncommented to set the date and time
//  rtc.setDOW(MONDAY);     // Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
//  rtc.setTime(15, 51, 0);     // Set the time to 12:00:00 (24hr format)
//  rtc.setDate(9, 11, 2017);   // Set the date to January 1st, 2014
}


int blinker(int state = 1) {
  if(state == 1) {
    if (active == true) {
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      delay(1000);              // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      delay(1000);  
      buttonCheck();
    }
  }
}

int buttonCheck() {
  Serial.println(digitalRead(11));
  if(digitalRead(11) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Button pushed");
    active = false;
    blinker(0);
  }
}


void loop()
{
  int hour = rtc.getTime().hour;
  int min = rtc.getTime().min;

  // Send time
  Serial.print(hour);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(min);
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.println(digitalRead(11));

  if(hour == 9 && min == 59) {
    active = true;
  }

  blinker();
  delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: You can read more about this [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html) about why this happens and about its benefits.